# How to show a container above another container in flutter?

Tags: flutter

when no input
[image: When no input]

when there is input
[image: When there is input]

Wanted to get the second container(output) above the first container(input) as soon user input something, refer image with input.

Code till now.

```
body: Center(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Visibility(
          visible: _showButton,
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            ),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Text(
                '$_outputText',
                maxLines: null,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: TextFormField(
            //controller: myController,
            //keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: null,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.white),
            cursorColor: Colors.white,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter Text',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.grey),
              labelText: 'Input',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.black),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 1.0,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 1.0,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              ),
            ),
            onChanged: onChange,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

I'm using stack because wanted to add animation later to the second container to show as a pop up from first container.

Comment: By default, Stack puts its children on top of each other centrally. You need to check out the use of Positioned and/or Aligned widgets with Stack.

Comment: Sorry, Stack positions it's children top left by default, same size children will simply cover each other. See this medium post for a good insight into stack. https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-stack-in-flutter-3264619b3a77

Comment: Stack has a alignment property

Comment: Sure, but that is used to modify the alignment of all children. You still need to use Aligned or Postitioned to control individual child positions.

Comment: Check `AnimatedContainer` [Reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html)

Comment: @dev-aentgs AnimatedContainer might not work here as there is two different container and one container should not be overlapping with the other.

Comment: Ok. I was sort of suggesting to use a single `AnimatedContainer` and change its properties when the user input is completed.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem from this https://youtu.be/DSdMfvmPQrM but unable to implement the same in my code. Any help will be appreciated.